# Search a string from a file using file handling in C

Tags: c, file-handling

1. A file is created named ITEM.txt that comprises names of items line by line(one item per line).
2. A particular item is to be searched.

This is what is done so far. We open the file in read mode and using an infinite loop, we read each character until we get a new line or we reach the end of file. Then we store those characters in a separate array and lastly compare the array contents with the order(item) that has been entered by the user.
The problem is for any item, the output is: couldn't find.

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int choice, quantity;
    char order[1000], a[1000];
    char c, e;
    int amount = 0, line_num = 0, j = 0;
    int price[1000] = {77, 100, 43, 35, 64, 125, 151, 91, 118, 184, 27, 47, 25, 100, 50, 59, 45, 350, 370, 530, 395, 460, 430, 620, 150, 145, 96, 81, 54, 94, 579, 565, 165, 206, 193, 198, 849, 184, 165, 75, 165, 126, 210, 280, 210, 189, 199, 350, 478, 440, 215, 207, 309, 139, 248, 204, 195, 253, 175, 90, 175, 329, 175, 199};
    int Quantity[1000] = {100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 1000,
                          5, 5, 5, 5, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 300, 500, 500, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
                          100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100};
    char q;
    printf("1.MENU\n2.ORDER\n3.PAY_BILL\n4.EXIT\n");
    printf("Enter choice : ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    FILE *ptr = NULL;
    FILE *p = NULL;
    while (choice < 4)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            ptr = fopen("DATABASE.txt", "r");
            while (1)
            {
                c = fgetc(ptr);
                if (c == EOF)
                {
                    break;
                }
                printf("%c", c);
            }
            printf("\n");
            fclose(ptr);
            break;
        case 2:
            while (1)
            {
                fflush(stdin);
            label:
                printf("What would you like to order: ");
                scanf("%[^\n]%*c", order);
                p = fopen("ITEM.txt", "r");

                int k = 0;
                while (1)
                {
                    e = tolower(fgetc(p));
                    if (e == EOF)
                    {
                        printf("couldn't find \n");
                        goto label;
                    }
                    while (e != '\n')
                    {
                        a[k++] = e;
                        e = tolower(fgetc(p));
                    }
                    line_num++;
                    k = 0;
                    if (strcmp(a, order) == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                fclose(p);
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Please Enter the Quantity(in numbers): ");
                scanf("%d", &quantity);
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Added to your cart\n");
                printf("\n");
                printf("Would you like to place another order?y/n: ");
                scanf("%c", &q);
                if (q == 'n')
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("Thank You For visiting our market....Have a nice day");
    return 0;
} ```


Any help is appreciated!!
````

Comment: The C specification explicitly says that passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to the `fflush` function is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And never use labels and `goto` instead of loop. Use actual loops instead, even if it means you need to add a little more logic to your program.

Comment: What is the data type of `e`? Please provide a [mre] (a complete minimal program with all `#include` directives and a function `main`).

Comment: I have entered the entire code block incase anyone needs them.

Answer (score 0):

[C strings need a null byte to mark the end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling), which you aren't adding to `a`. Do so with `a[k] = 0`.

Comment: okayy..I will check..thank You.